# How to skip checkout in classic pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a TFVC project using classic pipelines. Is it possible to disable checking out source code for specified stages?

Right now, each stage is doing a checkout of the whole source code by default. I can't find a task or a property that allows me to do a `checkout: none`, nor can I find anything in documentation about whether `checkout` task is supported in classic pipeline.

The tasks I'm trying to do: run PowerShell scripts from other repos - so I need to clone a repo from a different project, and then execute some ps files. This works fine on an `Agent Job`, but for `Agentless Job`, can't seem to run PowerShell scripts easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike a build pipeline (not release pipeline) using Git repository below, a build pipeline getting resources from TFVC repository in classic editor doesn't have the feature of `Don't sync sources` to skip `checkout` step. The `- chekout: none` expression is only used in a YAML pipeline rather than in classic editor and TFVC repository doesn't support YAML pipelines.

[image]

Since you don't want to use the sources from your TFVC repo during the pipeline run and expect to clone another Git repo in another project, you can directly select that repo in the `Get sources` section.
[image]

For this, you need to make sure the pipeline job authorization scope is `Project collection` instead of the default `Current project` in pipeline `Options` and `Project Settings`.
[image]

Besides, kindly be noted that we are unable to use a PowerShell task in an agent-less job (see [Agentless jobs supported tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agentless-tasks)).